# Why do scripts work when run from text editor but fail when run as an add-on

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

for example auto smooth set angle value fails when pie is run as an add-on
[image]
but it works when run from the text editor
[image]

this makes no sense to me or I cannot figure out what is wrong.
here is a link to the code of the complete pie script.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0abba8f7de314d38659b#file-pie-menu

Comment: Error message? `AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'scene'` ? If yes, see: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes Blender now restricts access to `bpy.context` and `bpy.data` while `register() / unregister()`.

Comment: Sometimes when figuring ot what causes a bug you stumble into other potential bugs, you define `UV_scale_X` class multiple times - make each unique.

Comment: don't have a space in your python file name. name it something like `some_pie_menu.py`.  it seems to work here, and does set the angle. In the event you get no warnings / errors you should start to look more carefully at other potential bugs and fixing those first.

Comment: @poor there is sadly no error message with the set autosmooth. What seems to be the issue is the step to check the angel degree and if 180 set it to 30. If I only use set to 30 anyway it all works fine. Sometimes the 180 check works but more often it does not.

Comment: Claas a common and time-tested technique to locate bugs is to remove as much as possible from your code while still being able to demonstrate the problem. You are trying to debug it as a whole, this takes more effort. If you've removed everything you can, and it works as an Add-on and a Script, then gradually add back sections of code, you might find the solution is counter intuitive.

Comment: Good point zeffii. It is not ideal to set the value back to 30 each time you turn auto smooth on off but in the end you will mainly turn autosmooth on once and be done.